# Tapestry IoC constructor and injection

Tags: inversion-of-control, tapestry

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    private MyAnotherClass myAnotherClass;

    public MyClass() {
        //Perform operations on myAnotherClass.
    }
}
```

I need to do some things in constructor which require an instance of `myAnotherClass`. Unfortunately `myAnotherClass` is injected after code in constructor is ran, which means I am performing operations on `null`...

I could of course instantiate it the classic way (`MyAnotherClass myAnotherClass = new MyAnotherClass()`) directly in constructor, but I don't think it is the right thing to do in this situation.

What solutions would you suggest to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best option:

```java
public class MyClass {
  private final MyAnotherClass myAnotherClass;

  public MyClass(MyAnotherClass other) {
    this.myAnotherClass = other;
    // And so forth
  }
}
```

T5-IoC will then use constructor injection so there's no need to 'new' up `MyClass` yourself. See [Defining Tapestry IOC Services](http://tapestry.apache.org/defining-tapestry-ioc-services.html#DefiningTapestryIOCServices-InjectingDependenciesforAutobuiltServices) for more info.

Alternatively:

```java
public class MyClass {
  @Inject
  private MyAnotherClass myAnotherClass;

  @PostInjection
  public void setupUsingOther() {
    // Called last, after fields are injected
  }
}
```