# @Inject fails to inject a field

Tags: tapestry

Tapestry @Inject is failing to inject a service in my POJO.  The service is bound way up in my Module...

```
public static void bind( ServiceBinder binder ) {
    ...
    binder.bind( DeviceProfileHelperService.class, DeviceProfileHelperServiceImpl.class );
    ...
}
```

...and I expected that @Inject would just be able to find it down in my POJO.

```
@Inject
private DeviceProfileHelperService deviceProfileHelperSvc;
...
@Override
public BasicDBObject makeEntity( String platform, String serialNumber, List<DBObject> configs ) {
    final BasicDBObject response = new BasicDBObject( "resp", configs );
    // FIXME:  deviceProfileHeplperSvc is null here, why?
    final String bindingUri = deviceProfileHelperSvc.makeBindURI( platform, serialNumber );
    response.append( "bindingUri", bindingUri );
    return response;
}
```

...but what actually happens is that the deviceProfileHelperSvc is null when I try to invoke it.  Where did I go wrong?  Shouldn't @Inject be able to resolve this based upon type from the binder.bind( DeviceProfileHelperService.class, DeviceProfileHelperServiceImpl.class ) binding set up in my Module?

I doubt it matters, but we are Tapestry 5.3.6.

Comment: Maybe a clue here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121308/tapestry-ioc-constructor-and-injection

Answer (score 1):

Tapestry can only @Inject into services it manages. I can only assume that you have instantiated your "POJO" yourself using "new"

Comment: Yep.  That is correct.  The POJO that I'm attempting the @Inject is invoked itself from a Service that Tapestry is directly managing.  Are you saying that my POJO needs to go through the whole bind() thing thus becoming a service?  This seems a little redundant to me, but I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: Bound services are singletons. If you want to create multiple beans at runtime you'll probably want to consider `ObjectLocator.autobuild()`

Comment: You are on the right path, Lance.  The POJO I'm trying to @Inject into is effectively a Singleton; its only instantiation is in the constructor of an object that is itself a Tapestry service.  I'm explicitly passing the dependency in right now to just get the kid working.  I'll try the whole service bind thing once I'm up and running.  Your answer is helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, well... The whole idea of IOC is that you never instantiate services yourself. That's the job of the IOC container.

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  I just didn't really expect having to register everything that was going to participate in the Injection stuff.  I had expected that a POJO could just arbitrarily Inject from the IOC container without having to fully integrate with it.  If I understand you correctly, for my POJO to Inject some other service, I have to introduce my POJO to the IOC container, thus losing the ability to just new them up at will.  I may be misunderstanding this issue entirely, but I've got some things to try which could lead to clarity.

Comment: If you just `new` up a class - how would you expect T5-IoC to know about it and then arbitrary inject services? It simply can't. As you stated, T5-IoC needs to know about every class that participates in the injection stuff. If you're newing up instances at will, then `autobuild()` is the way forward.

Comment: Well... It could be done via a [jvm agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#ClassPrepare) but that's far too messy to consider ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you have only a single implementation of `DeviceProfileHelperService`, try using the `@Named` attribute on the implementation of the `DeviceProfileHelperService` to identify it.

e.g.

```
@Named
public class DeviceProfileHelperServiceImpl implements DeviceProfileHelperService {
  ...
}
```

Comment: No joy.  That didn't work.  I would like to know why you got downvoted, though.

Comment: As would I... Honestly most of my Java IoC experience is in Spring, but based on my understanding of JSR-330 `@Named` is synonymous with their `@Component` etc. annotations. In fact several resources online recommend using the default JSR-330 over Spring's because it is more portable. Hopefully you find an answer that works!